# Creating Vector Function File

Tags: matlab

I wish to create a vector function in Matlab, defined as the following:

[image]

The code I have so far:

```
function [Ex, Ey, Ez] = E_field()
syms x y z
con = -2.8E+8;
E = con*z.^3;
Ex = matlabFunction(E(1));
Ey = matlabFunction(E(2));
Ez = matlabFunction(E(3));
end
```

However, I get this error when this function is being referenced when Matlab's ode solver is running:

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).
Error in sym/subsref (line 890)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);
Error in E_field (line 7)
Ey = matlabFunction(E(2));
```

I do not see why this wouldn't work as I have a very similar function file that is also being referenced but doesn't throw and error:

```
function [Bx, By, Bz] = B_test()
Bfieldstrength = 0.64; %In (Teslas)
magvol = 3.218E-6; %In (m)
mu0 = (4*pi)*10^-7;
magnetization = (Bfieldstrength*magvol)/mu0;
syms x y z
m = [0,0,magnetization];
r = [x, y, z];
B = mu0*(((dot(m,r)*r*3)/norm(r)^5) - m/norm(r)^3);
Bx = matlabFunction(B(1));
By = matlabFunction(B(2));
Bz = matlabFunction(B(3));
end
```

I know the E-field file has only one component in it which may be why Matlab can't identify E(1) or E(2) to be just a "symbolic zero" (And assigns E to E(1)) so how can I go about making it understand that the E(1) and E(2) components are zero while E(3) is not? I've read through all of Matlab's documentation for their "matlabFunction" but none of it was useful for this case.

The main code "collisions7.m" uses ode15s and calls the function file "bdipuniodefun.m". The rest of the files: "engen.m", maxdis.m" and posgen.m" are all referenced by the main code but do not cause issues. The main issue is when the main code calls "bdipodefun.m" because the solver either throws an error or it completely ignores the e field file and produces incorrect solutions.

Here is a link to the code in question: https://github.com/tomkeaton/Planeterrella

Comment: Type those commands on the command line, and examine their results. Alternatively, turn on the debugger and step through your function, examining the values you create as you do so. You'll see that `E` is a scalar, it has only one value. `E(2)` therefore indexes out of bounds. Note that you define `x` and `y` as symbolic variables, but never use them!

Comment: That said, there is no reason whatsoever to use symbolic math for what you do. Simply write `Ez = @(z) -2.8E+8 * z.^3; Ez(0.2)`.

Comment: There is a big difference between your `E_field` and your `B_test`: the use of symbolic variables. Avoid at at all costs!. As @CrisLuengo adviced: use a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @Cris Luego there is a set of odes that I want to solve within a function file and one of the equations references this electric field. I tried the method you are talking about by defining E within the function file itself however, the solver did not recognize it that way, which is why I am doing it symbolically.

Comment: Then maybe [edit] your question to include a [mre] for a call to the ODE solver for that function, so we can help you get that working. The symbolic variables don't add anything there.

Comment: The main code that contains the ode solver and references the function file who's equations reference the e and b field function files is about 400 lines long. I cannot attach a file from what I could see and I don't think anyone is interested in looking through that much code which is why I only posted this much and hoped to just recreate the b field function file in order to fix the issue. I also cannot reproduce the issue with much simpler code when I tried. However, I will still add it all so you can see it in full.